# How to parse the data points from an interactive table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to know how I can parse the data points contained in an interactive table using Python. It seems that I cannot find the respective tags containing the data. Are there any other ways out?

Here is the outline of the table to be parsed:
[image: Here is the outline of the table to be parsed]

I used pretty standard ways to parse the link at first, but the numbers inside the table did not show up in the `print` output. I am not sure what to do next.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = requests.get("http://www.msri.cn/xyEnNCFIView")
soup = bs(url.content, "html.parser")
content = soup.find_all(id="tab-content")
print(content)
```

Comment: Essential information for understanding the question should not be behind a link. Also, you should show your code and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the network tab on developer console, you just need to perform :

```
POST http://www.msri.cn/ncfi/query
```

You don't need to send any data in the body, it seems it always sends the same output (unless logged-in I assume)

The following will get the data and build a graph using matplotlib :

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

r = requests.post("http://www.msri.cn/ncfi/query")
result = r.json()

dates = [ datetime.strptime(t["name"], '%Y-%m-%d') for t in result["data"]["categories"]]
values = [ float(t["value"]) for t in result["data"]["dataset"][0]["set"]]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=365))
plt.plot(dates, values)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel('Index')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.savefig("capture.png")
```

Checkout [this repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/PlotScrape) which shows the graph at the end